# Jquery Cycle plugin timeout speeds up after click or hover?

Tags: jquery-plugins, hover, jquery-cycle, event-bubbling

I am using the Jquery Cycle to create a slideshow with thumbnail pagers. The slideshow should pause when the thumbnail is hovered.

However, I have noticed that if the thumbs are clicked rapidly or if the mouse is moved over them rapidly, the timeout changes & even skips images! (FireFox / IE9).

I tried a fix recommended here to prevent bubbling but the Cycle would not load:

```
$.click(function(event){ 
event.preventDefault(); 
event.stopPropagation(); 
})
```

This had allowed the Cycle to load but did not solve the issue:

```
$('#nav li a').onmouseenter(function(event){ 
event.preventDefault(); 
event.stopPropagation(); 
})
```

These are my settings & any advice is appreciated:

```
$('#slideshow').before('<ul id="nav">').cycle({     
fx:      'scrollLeft',
delay:   2000,
sync:    1,         
speed:   1500,      
timeout: 3000,
manualTrump:   true,
pager:  '#nav',
pagerEvent: 'mouseover', 
pauseOnPagerHover: true, 
slideExpr: 'img', 
allowPagerClickBubble: false, 
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
return '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src=\"' + slide.src + '" width="30" height="30"></a></li>';
} 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bug fix: Jquery Cycle Version: 2.9999.3 (08-MAR-2012)